# Making a label and input box all even throughout the form

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I found a link [CSS tricks](https://css-tricks.com/float-labels-css/) but it did not work. In fact it made my label sit on top of my input field. I am using bootstrap and right now if I have a label `Last Name` and one below it `name` the are off set. I am trying to get the label and input fields to be even.

Example:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">
    <label>Last Name:</label>
    <input type="text" class="textBoxSize" name="lastname" [(ngModel)]="user.lastName">
</div>

<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">
    <label>First Name:</label>
    <input type="text" class="textBoxSize" name="firstname" [(ngModel)]="user.lastName">
</div>

<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">
    <label>MI:</label>
    <input type="text" class="textBoxSizeSmall" name="middleName" [(ngModel)]="user.lastName">
</div>
```

I know `[(ngModel)]` is the same.

Comment: Hi Drew, you need to show us your code so that we have a [mcve] of what you have so far.

Comment: @MichaelCoker here is a small sample. The form is pretty big

Comment: Without a fiddle showing working HTML/CSS, it's impossible to diagnose. Have you reviewed the documentation: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms ?

Comment: @TerraElise  
here is it is plnkr.co/edit/qDt1xRnPJzIL5eAU0AjP?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using Bootstrap already, I suggest using their existing method for labels & elements in a horizontal layout by way of their grid classes. See: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal and the updated plunkr you'd have to further edit as needed: http://plnkr.co/edit/k3A4jZPdkQbysfmOcXFi?p=preview

Otherwise, a manual fix would be to make the labels float left and a set width, but set widths on labels & form fields defeat the purpose of responsive.

```
label {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
}
```